# Program structure for a database of callable Python objects

Tags: python, database, oop, data-structures

I am working on a project that requires a large database of python objects, each of which has exactly two methods: `__init__` and `__call__`. The `init` defines attributes specific to each object, while the `call` method contains the definition of a function parametrized by the attributes. Right now, I am representing this database using a large `.py` file that contains all of the objects. For example, first two entries in the file `myfuncs.py` are something like

```
class Alice:
    def __init__(self, a=10, b=4):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.color = "red"

    def __call__(self, X):
        return X**2 + self.a + self.b

class Timmy:
    def __init__(self, h=1):
        self.a = a
        self.color = "blue"    

    def __call__(self, X):
        return X**4*self.h
```

I might use these classes in a separate program:

```
from myfuncs import Alice
model = Alice(a=10)
y = model(15)
print("The value was ", str(y), " and the color is ", model.color)
```

Notice that the `init` method for both objects contains a hard-coded attribute `color` and a value that is specific to that object. All objects in the database have this attribute, and currently the only way to associate this attribute with the object is through a hard-coded value in the constructor.

Rather than having one long `.py` file with a bunch of objects (and a lot of boilerplate code), it seems to me like there should be some way to define a database of objects, each with an attribute `color` and another attribute `function` that contains the contents of the `__call__()` method and default keyword arguments. However, after importing a specific object I need it to be treated like a native Python function, and so I'm not sure that storing the functions as strings and then using `exec` will work.

While my minimal example may seem contrived, in my application these objects contain in their `call` methods complex mathematical formula written as Python functions, the keyword args are the parameter values in these formulae, and the property `color` is a label associated with each formula that denotes its symmetry group (which is something I know about each function from external info).

What is the best way to structure my project?

Comment: Can you show how you're using the classes later?

Comment: Thank you, I added an example import and a little more info about my application (a database of complex mathematical formulae)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a slightly better way that gets rid of a lot of boilerplate:

```py
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class BaseModel(ABC):
    color: str

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

    @abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, x):
        ...


class Alice(BaseModel):
    color = 'red'
    b = 4

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x ** 2 + self.a + self.b


class Timmy(BaseModel):
    color = 'blue'
    h = 1

    def __call__(self, x):
        return x ** 4 * self.h
```

This way you only need to define the parts that change from class to class.

Also you can express your print like this:

```py
print(f"The value was {y} and the color is {model.color}")
```